# How to pass an array (Range.Value) to a native .NET type without looping?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, arraylist, com

What I am trying to do is populate an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.100).aspx) using [`.AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange(v=vs.100).aspx) method in VBA using late binding on native C# `ArrayList`, but I can't figure out how to pass an object other than another `ArrayList` to it as argument... anything else I have tried so far fails...

So basically what I am doing now *(Note: `list` is C#'s `ArrayList` via mscorlib.dll)*

```
Dim list as Object
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5
    list.Add Range("A" & i).Value2
Next
```

But this is quite inefficient and ugly if for example `i` can be `= 500K`.

In VBA this also works:

```
ArrayList1.AddRange ArrayList2
```

But what I really need/would like is to pass an array instead of `ArrayList2`

So [I heard I can pass an array to the `.AddRange()` parameter in .NET.](http://dotnetfluent.com/reference/csharp-reference/collections-generics/arraylist/addrange/using-addrange-to-add-an-array-into-an-arraylist-in-c/) I tested it in a small C# console application and it seemed to work just fine. The below works just fine in a pure C# console application.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
string[] strArr = new string[1];
strArr[0] = "hello";
list.AddRange(strArr);
```

So going back to my VBA module trying to do the *same* it fails..

```
Dim arr(1) As Variant
arr(0) = "WHY!?"

Dim arrr As Variant
arrr = Range("A1:A5").Value

list.AddRange arr                     ' Fail
list.AddRange arrr                    ' Fail
list.AddRange Range("A1:A5").Value    ' Fail
```

Note: I have tried passing a native VBA Array of Variants and `Collection`, Ranges - everything except another `ArrayList` failed.

**How do I pass a native VBA array as a parameter to an `ArrayList`**?

Or any alternative for creating a collection from Range without looping??

<sub>Bonus question: *Or maybe there is another built-in .Net COM Visible Collection that can be populated from VBA `Range` Object or Array without looping and that already has a `.Reverse`?</sub>

NOTE: **I am aware that I can make a .dll wrapper to achieve this but I am interested in native solutions - if any exist**.

---

## Update

To better illustrate why I want to completely avoid explicit iteration - here's an example (*it uses only one column for simplicity*)

```
Sub Main()

    ' Initialize the .NET's ArrayList
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")


    ' There are two ways to populate the list.
    ' I selected this one as it's more efficient than a loop on a small set
    ' For details, see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-optimization
    list.Add Range("A1")
    list.Add Range("A2")
    list.Add Range("A3")
    list.Add Range("A4")
    list.Add Range("A5") ' It's OK with only five values but not with 50K.

    ' Alternative way to populate the list
    ' According to the above link this method has a worse performance
    'Dim i As Long
    'Dim arr2 As Variant
    'arr2 = Range("A1:A5").Value2
    'For i = 1 To 5
    '    list.Add arr2(i, 1)
    'Next

    ' Call native ArrayList.Reverse
    ' Note: no looping required!
    list.Reverse

    ' Get an array from the list
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = list.ToArray

    ' Print reversed to Immediate Window
    'Debug.Print Join(arr, Chr(10))

    ' Print reversed list to spreadsheet starting at B1
    Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

Please notice: the only time I have to loop is to populate the list (ArrayList) what I would love to do would be just to find a way to load the `arr2` into an ArrayList or another .NET compatible type without loops.

At this point I see that there is no native/built-in way to do so that's why I think I am going to try to implement my own way and maybe if it works out submit an update for the Interop library.

Comment: The argument to AddRange has to implement ICollection.  The VBA arrays do not (nor does the interop layer simulate this, apparently).

Comment: why not load the data from the range into an array in one step (as you are doing now) then loop through that array? As it is in memory (the slow step is querying Range.Value) it should have a fairly minor performance impact.

Comment: I see the tiny note about `.Reverse` - is there a specific use case you could describe? I could imagine a special-purpose native VBA data structure could provide satisfactory performance, assuming that's the reason you would want to use the .NET library.

Comment: @Blackhawk ignore the .Reverse actually. I originally thought that If I can pass `Range.Value` to .Net in an `ArrayList` form (as a single column, or just as multi-dimensional array) I could easily use already implemented methods and .Reverse was just an example. The whole point is to gather an array based on Range in VBA (in one go Range.Value with no looping) and then pass that onto a native .Net type also with no looping

Comment: I think even using `.AddRange(ICollection)` natively in .NET causes looping to copy items behind the scenes.  However, there is a method of ArrayList, `.Adapter(IList)` that simply wraps an IList and *DOESN'T* copy it, using the IList methods to modify it in place! I could take a swing at implementing that interface if that would be interesting to you.  Of course, it would still require a "compatibility layer" of VBA wrapper classes to make it work right.  The whole api could be reduced to a `WrapperFactory(var as Variant)` function, but you'd have the baggage of the classes to carry.

Comment: [Adapter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#3e3f6715773d6643): "Creates a ArrayList wrapper for a particular IList.  This does not copy the contents of the IList, but only wraps the ILIst.  So any changes to the underlying list will affect the ArrayList.  This would be useful if you want to Reverse a subrange of an IList, or want to use a generic BinarySearch or Sort method without implementing one yourself. However, since these methods are generic, the performance may not be nearly as good for some operations as they would be on the IList itself."

Comment: @Blackhawk I see, I see. Thank you but do not have a go at implementing it. There must be a way to pass a VBA array to a compatible .Net data type without explicitly looping. I know that even the `AddRange` loops under the hood but I am pretty sure it is faster than doing it explicitly - even working "in" memory.

Comment: Do you know about `x = Range(..).Resize(500,1).Value` which transfers multiple cells at the same time as an 2D `object[,]` array?

Comment: @ja72 pardon me if I misunderstood you but how is `x = Range(..).Resize(500,1).Value` any different from `Range().Value` with multiple columns? Both return a Variant() array

Comment: It is more efficient than current use of picking one by one cells, and as long as the array fits in memory the `.Value` operation is relatively efficient. You can include multiple columns in one call.

Comment: @mehow "There must be a way to pass a VBA array to a compatible .Net data type without explicitly looping"  Why must there be?  They are different platforms!

Comment: @DStanley I was really hoping there someone before would have thought of that... we got VSTO and it's possible when you reference the Excel Object Model so why wouldn't it be possible the other way around...

Comment: .NET can marshal from VBA collection to .NET collection (since it was built _after_ VBA); VBA can not.  FWIW .NET probably loops internally since VBA and .NET allocate memory differently (I don't think you can just copy memory blocks to "copy" the collection.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   list.AddRange Range("A1:A5").Value
```

The range's Value gets marshaled as an *array*.  That's about the most basic .NET type you can imagine of course.  This one however has bells on, it is not a "normal" .NET array.  VBA is a runtime environment that likes to create arrays whose first element starts at index 1.  That's a *non-conformant* array type in .NET, the CLR likes arrays whose first element starts at index 0.  The only .NET type you can use for those is the System.Array class.

An extra complication is that the array is a *two-dimensional* array.  That puts the kibosh on your attempts to get them converted to an ArrayList, multi-dimensional arrays don't have an enumerator.

So this code works just fine:

```
    public void AddRange(object arg) {
        var arr = (Array)arg;
        for (int ix = ar.GetLowerBound(0); ix <= arr2.GetUpperBound(0); ++ix) {
            Debug.Print(arr.GetValue(ix, 1).ToString());
        } 
    }
```

You probably don't care for that too much.  You could use a little accessor class that wraps the awkward Array and *acts* like a vector:

```
class Vba1DRange : IEnumerable<double> {
    private Array arr;
    public Vba1DRange(object vba) {
        arr = (Array)vba;
    }
    public double this[int index] {
        get { return Convert.ToDouble(arr.GetValue(index + 1, 1)); }
        set { arr.SetValue(value, index + 1, 1); }
    }
    public int Length { get { return arr.GetUpperBound(0); } }
    public IEnumerator<double> GetEnumerator() {
        int upper = Length;
        for (int index = 0; index < upper; ++index)
            yield return this[index];
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Now you can write it the "natural" way:

```
    public void AddRange(object arg) {
        var arr = new Vba1DRange(arg);
        foreach (double elem in arr) {
            Debug.Print(elem.ToString());
        }
        // or:
        for (int ix = 0; ix < arr.Length; ++ix) {
            Debug.Print(arr[ix].ToString());
        }
        // or:
        var list = new List<double>(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof of concept as an expansion of @phoog's comment. As he points out, the [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method takes an [ICollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#3e3f6715773d6643).

**Implementing ICollection**

In the VBA IDE, add a reference to mscorlib.tlb: Tools--->References, then browse to find your .NET Framework mscorlib.tlb. Mine was at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.XXXXX\mscorlib.tlb".

Create a new class called "clsWrapLongArray" as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements ICollection
Dim m_lngArr() As Long

Public Sub LoadArray(lngArr() As Long)
    m_lngArr = lngArr
End Sub

Private Sub ICollection_CopyTo(ByVal arr As mscorlib.Array, ByVal index As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = LBound(m_lngArr)
    For i = index To index + (ICollection_Count - 1)
        arr.SetValue m_lngArr(j), i
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Property Get ICollection_Count() As Long
    ICollection_Count = UBound(m_lngArr) - LBound(m_lngArr) + 1
End Property

Private Property Get ICollection_IsSynchronized() As Boolean
    'Never called for this example, so I'm leaving it blank
End Property

Private Property Get ICollection_SyncRoot() As Variant
    'Never called for this example, so I'm leaving it blank
End Property
```

[Here is the `Array.SetValue` method used.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kk3bwkb0)

Create a new module called "mdlMain" to run the example:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()

    Dim arr(0 To 3) As Long

    arr(0) = 1
    arr(1) = 2
    arr(2) = 3
    arr(3) = 4

    Dim ArrList As ArrayList
    Set ArrList = New ArrayList

    Dim wrap As clsWrapLongArray
    Set wrap = New clsWrapLongArray
    wrap.LoadArray arr
    ArrList.AddRange wrap
End Sub
```

If you put a breakpoint on the `End Sub` and run `Main()`, you can see by inspecting `ArrList` in the immediate window that it contains the 4 values added from the Long array.  You can also step through the code to see that `ArrayList` actually calls the ICollection interface members `Count` and `CopyTo` to make it happen.

I could see that it might be possible to expand on this idea to create Factory functions to wrap types like Excel Ranges, VBA Arrays, Collections, etc.

This same method works with String arrays! :D

I found some very close answers by Googling `"System.ArrayList" "SAFEARRAY"` and `"System.Array" "SAFEARRAY"` and refining with "COM Marshaling", since VBA arrays are COM SAFEARRAYs, but nothing quite explained how one might convert them for use in .NET calls.

Answer (score 1):

It's inefficient because `.Value2` is a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) call. Calling it thousands of times adds a lot of interop overhead. Adding items to an array in a loop should be MUCH faster:

```
Dim list as Object
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim i As Long
Dim a as Variant
a = Range("A1:A5").Value2
For i = 1 To 5
    list.Add a(i,1)
Next
```

> How do I pass a native VBA array as a parameter to an ArrayList?

I don't think you can - a native VBA array is *not* an `ICollection`, so the only way to *create* one would be to copy the values in a loop.

The reason it works in a C# console application is because arrays in C# *are* `ICollection`s, so the `AddRange` method accepts them just fine.

Comment: But `Value2` is only called once in the example. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ja72 Yes: `Value2` is within a loop, so it's called multiple times.

Comment: Is there an outer loop not shown? Above the loop does not call `Value2`.

Comment: Are you asking about _my_ answer or the original question?  The original question calls `Value2` in a loop - my answer does not.

Comment: I agree, so I do not understand why it got downvoted. I think this is the way to go.

Comment: Why?  If it's because of performance have you measured it with `.Value2` outside the loop to see if the performance improved?  If it's for code clarity you could create a helper method but I sincerely doubt you can avoid having a loop at some level.