# Late binding an array

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, vba, com

I am seriously stumped as I can't find **anything** on late binding an array in VBA. Is this even possible? If yes, how? If not - why?

Note: I don't mind if it's possible using a native .Net/C# types like

```
Dim o as Object
set o = CreateObject("System.Array")
```

Even though the [`System.Array` is COM visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array) it seems impossible to instantiate it.

Any idea how to late bind an array data type in VBA?

<sub>*please, don't mention Dictionary or Collections as this question is quite specific to arrays*</sub>

---

Additional info:

This is kind of a follow up on [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683815/how-to-pass-an-array-range-value-to-a-native-net-type-without-looping). Since it seems impossible to pass a native VBA array to a native .Net collection without looping I was just wondering whether it's possible to late bind an array as both as seem safearrays which would mean they are compatible and therefore transfering a VBA array to a .Net one would be possible - please correct me if I am completely wrong.

Comment: I am curious as to what you think a method that takes a .NET array to return a .NET collection is doing internally? (just r.e. your previous question, which I think I remember vaguely)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the exact question: Is it: 1) late-bind in VBA to a VBA array, 2) late-bind in C# to a VBA array, or 3)...late-bind in VBA to a .NET array? (it looks like number 3 I think)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey it's the 3rd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  set o = CreateObject("System.Array")
```

System.Array is an **abstract** class.  So no, that can't possibly work.  Array types are special, they are normally created by the compiler.  The backdoor is Type.MakeArrayType() and you can construct *that* one.

Nothing you'd want to use.  Don't try so hard, any VBA array is converted to System.Array already.  It is just often a *non-conformant* array, one that doesn't have its first element at index 0.  VBA likes 1, unless you use syntax like `Dim arr(0 To 3) As Double` or have `Option Base 0` in effect.  Not always possible, use Array.GetValue() to access a non-conformant array.  Review your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23769107/17034) for a sample accessor wrapper.