# Passing a System.Collections.Ilist to a function from VBA

Tags: vba, com-interop

I have a COM object from a .NET assembly. One parameter of one method is of type [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) (the non-generic IList not IList. How do I pass an array of integers (VBA longs) to it from inside of VBA? I've tried the following:

```
Dim foo(4) As Long
Dim foo(4) As Integer
Dim foo(4) As Variant
Dim foo As Variant
Dim foo(4) as Variant
Dim foo As object
Dim foo(4) as object
```

The error I get is: **ByRef argument type mismatch**

Comment: Do you know what specific methods of this IList are called within the COM object? It's possible to implement an IList wrapper for Integer arrays within VBA... but it would be easiest if you can determine which subset of the methods/properties actually need to be implemented.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the COM object's code? If so, it may be simpler to write a wrapper for it on the .NET side... See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683815/how-to-pass-an-array-range-value-to-a-native-net-type-without-looping?noredirect=1#comment36544134_23683815) for details.

Comment: Or yeah instead of a wrapper like my answer try to implement `IList` in VBA with the technique @Blackhawk [demonstrated in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23689182/2140173)